# Required only, if other field has special value?

Tags: php, yii

Is it possible to do this. 
I am using `Yii 1.1`

```
 public function rules()
        {
         return array(
                array('user_firstname, user_lastname, user_username, user_password,user_mobile,user_email', 'required','on'=>'createuser'),
             if ($this->user_role > 2 )
               {
                  array('user_special_permission, 'required'),    
                    }

                array('user_email, user_username, user_password', 'length', 'max'=>255),
                array('user_active, user_deleted', 'length', 'max'=>1),             
                // The following rule is used by search().
                // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                array('user_id, user_firstname, user_lastname, user_mobile, user_email, user_username, user_password, user_last_login, user_num_logins, user_num_failed_logins, user_active, user_deleted', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            );
        }
```

I want `user_special_permission` `required` only if `user_role >2`

Comment: Is this Yii 1.1 or Yii 2? You could use scenarios or a custom validator, how this works depends on the API version.

Comment: I am using Yii 1.1

Comment: did my solution worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Yii 1.1 you can implement a custom validation rule in your Model class as follows:

In your `rules` array add:

```
array('user_special_permission, 'role_validation'),
```

Then create a function `role_validation`:

```
public function role_validation($attribute, $params)
{
     if ($this->user_role > 2 && empty($this->user_special_permission)) {
          $this->addError('user_special_permission','Special Permission required.');
     }
}
```

You can adjust the attribute for which the error message is displayed, instead of `user_special_permission` for instance `user_role`

See [Declaring Validation Rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules) for more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible in yii 1
you can use filters. the code will be

```
array('user_special_permission, 'required','when'=>function($model){ 
    return $model->user_role>2; 
 } 
),
```